# iOS crash when built with one version of Xcode, no crash with another version

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to debug a crash that happens at a fundamental part of the app experience on a particular iOS version, but when I use the (newer) dev tools for that version, the crash does not occur.

How can I get a GDB session on version of an app that was installed with another SDK version?

Comment: Aye, fair.I thought the facts I was mentioning (it exists, there is a newer version of Xcode that runs with it) were covered by publicly released information by Apple (see http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action while logged out), thus falling under that particular clause of the NDA, but it's not productive to discuss it and IANAL. I'll reword the question to make it more abstract. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can build the app in Xcode 4.1 and deploy it to an iOS 5.0 device via TestFlight: https://testflightapp.com/

Comment: I can, but how do I get it in a debugger after that? The crash report shows me a crash in UITableView, but that's not good enough for me because it's something that I'm doing that's causing it

Comment: Under the Product menu in Xcode, you can try to "Attach To Process" after you've launched the app on the iOS device.

Comment: Very good, thank you. And actually, somehow restarting my computer with the device attached made it think the device was suitable for debugging, so that worked out.